# Plot a list of tuples, consisting of a datetime object and a numeric value

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, data-visualization

I have a dictionary where the value is a list of tuples. The tuple consists of a datetime object and a numeric value, e.g.:

```py
{
    'option1': [
        (datetime.datetime(2021, 8, 6, 6, 11, 29), 2480.82),
        (datetime.datetime(2021, 8, 6, 6, 21, 36), 2499.14),
        (datetime.datetime(2021, 8, 6, 6, 31, 40), 2488.59),
        (datetime.datetime(2021, 8, 6, 6, 41, 44), 2486.51),
    ],
    'option2': [
        (datetime.datetime(2021, 8, 6, 6, 11, 30), 560.56),
        (datetime.datetime(2021, 8, 6, 6, 21, 36), 1100.19),
        (datetime.datetime(2021, 8, 6, 6, 31, 40), 795.54),
        (datetime.datetime(2021, 8, 6, 6, 41, 44), 873.97),
    ],
}
```

Now I would like to plot values against time, one line for every key (in this case "option1" and "option2"). With `matplotlib`, I started looping over the `dict.items()`, nested looping over the list, and then dissecting the tuple. However, I wonder if there is a more elegant way, either in `matplotlib` or any other visualization library. I do not neccessarily need to use `matplotlib`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`zip` built-in function together with argument unpacking would do the trick:

```
import datetime

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = {
    'option1': [
        (datetime.datetime(2021, 8, 6, 6, 11, 29), 2480.82),
        (datetime.datetime(2021, 8, 6, 6, 21, 36), 2499.14),
        (datetime.datetime(2021, 8, 6, 6, 31, 40), 2488.59),
        (datetime.datetime(2021, 8, 6, 6, 41, 44), 2486.51),
    ],
    'option2': [
        (datetime.datetime(2021, 8, 6, 6, 11, 30), 560.56),
        (datetime.datetime(2021, 8, 6, 6, 21, 36), 1100.19),
        (datetime.datetime(2021, 8, 6, 6, 31, 40), 795.54),
        (datetime.datetime(2021, 8, 6, 6, 41, 44), 873.97),
    ],
}

for option, tuples in data.items():
    x, y = zip(*tuples)
    plt.plot(x, y, label=option)

plt.legend()
plt.show()
```